# System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'CgtFpAccessCSD200Dotnet' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, sdk, fingerprint

Iam trying to integrate fingerprint reader to my web application.My Device is 3M Cogent CSD200.but it fails to execute and the above error is being displayed.Can anybody help me with this error

Comment: Please show your code, and show on which line the error occurs..

Comment: Iam not getting the error during debug...I got this error after I hosted my website in IIS

Comment: Well is that dependency on the server with your app? you need to debug these things

Comment: Check whether your all assembly references are there in hosted location. I mean that dll files in bin folder.

Comment: Yes..i have that in my hosted location..

Comment: then its missing some of its dependencies

Comment: what kind of dependencies..??? i mean..do u have any idea..?

Comment: Have you added the reference to CgtFpAccessCSD200Dotnet.dll ??

Comment: ya..i have added that..CgtFpAccessCSD200Dotnet.dll.The error says Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'CgtFpAccessCSD200Dotnet' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be you are facing the problem with your website after deploying on server.

Then you need to adjust your application pool to Enable 32-Bit Applications.

**Steps:**

- Open IIS Manager
- Click on Application Pools
- Select whatever application pool you are using
- From right pane, click Advanced Settings...
- Set Enable 32-Bit Applications to True